# WSO2 IS and mod-auth-mellon for SSO

Tags: apache, authentication, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

We are attempting to use WSO2 IS and Apache+mod-auth-mellon to do single sign-on among different Apaches.

This is regarding getting the SSO part working among multiple Apache instances:

I got a 1st Apache+mod-auth-mellon working with WSO2 IS.  On the WSO2 Admin, I added an Identity provider and a Service provider.

After getting login working with the 1st Apache instance, I stood up a 2nd Apache (+mod_auth_mellon), and added a 2nd Service Provider, but I found that, in order to get the login into that 2nd Apache instance working, I had to add an additional ACS URL pointing to the 2nd Apache in the 1st Service Provider (in the WSO2 IS Admin) and vice-versa.

I think that the ACS URL that I had to add was the one ending in "postResponse".

Is this (having to add these "cross" ACSes to multiple Service Providers) a "normal" requirement with SAML-based SSO?  Or is it something specific with mod_auth_mellon and WSO2 IS?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your second Apache (+mod_auth_mellon) also picks the same Service Provider (1st Service Provider) from WSO2 IS. You can confirm this by deleting the 2nd Service Provider from IS and keeping both ACS URLs in one Service Provider. If you can still login to the 2nd Apache, both are served with one service provider. I am not familiar with mod_auth_mellon but from WSO2 IS side, there's no need to add cross ACSs for two SPs.

WSO2 IS decides which Service Provider to choose according to the value of issuer in the SAML request sent by the Application (In your case Apache+mod_auth_mellon). i.e issuer value in SAML request should be equal to the issuer value in SSO Service Provider configuration. If you need two Service Provider configurations, your two Apaches should send two different issuer values in requests.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and for the info that you provided.  That information helped me re-look at the configuration for the 2nd SP/Apache and I found the problem.  In the SP metadata.xml file for that 2nd SP, I had left the first Apache's hostname as the entity id.  I fixed that and SSO is now working even without the "cross" ACS URLs!

Comment: Great :) Really glad to hear that.